# Extract type of last element of tuple in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Essentially, what I am trying to write is a function that accepts an array of different types, (do something with that), and then return a type based on only the last element in that array (previous elements have been processed, but only the last element is used for the return value).

I know I can write a function that returns an array based off of *all* element types as follows.

```js
function arraymod<T extends unknown[]>(
  ...input: {
    [index in keyof T]: ParamType<T[index]>
  }
): T {
  return input.map(unparam);
}
```

What I want is a function that does something like this.

```js
function takelast<T extends unknown[]>(
  ...input: {
    [index in keyof T]: ParamType<T[index]>
  }
): LastElementOf<T> /* What would this return type be? */ {
  return unparam(input[input.length - 1]);
```

(`ParamType<T>` and `unparam` are just some example types/functions for illustration)

**How can I write a type `LastElementOf<T>` that gives the type of the last element of a tuple `T` (or array, eventhough that would just be type of any element).**

Comment: Please include ParamType

Comment: @wonderflame yeah I just realised I worded my question kind of poorly, the functions are just examples and aren't important for the question itself. What I am looking for is a way to write a type `LastElementOf<T>` to find the type of the last element of the tuple `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must use [infer keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to achieve this result.

We are going to check the array to extend `infer` last item and the rest of them, which we don't care about:

```
type LastElementOf<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [...unknown[], infer Last]
  ? Last
  : never;
```

`...unknown[]` will be first items except the last one, and the last one will be the `infer Last`

Usage:

```
type Case1 = LastElementOf<[]>; // never
type Case2 = LastElementOf<['dasd']>; // "dasd'
type Case3 = LastElementOf<['string', 12, false]>; // false
type Case4 = LastElementOf<readonly ['string', 12, false]>; // false
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AUQDYQLYQHbAPIBmAPACpQQAewOAJglAE4Rw0D22qIUArtgNbZWAd2wBtALoA+KAF4oZStWx1GzNhy6iAUFCgA6A7wHCx4gDQ6oAS2wEIDWImAXxlgPyOklgFxRsEADd7AG4tLVBIKABhRAgARllPFHQsXEIiCUlgqAB6HL9A+3DwaBiECAAmRPgkNEwcfGJRAHIaRBpmqWy8qAAiNoQO4siyiABmaqc61MaM5qQGGwBzZrMoOIq1gjhUcq7c-O3diGHS2IAWSdqUhvSmFnZOKBaF5dX1zagjvayDr53ylogA)